# telepot allowed users/chat ID

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

I'm building a telepot telegram bot on python 3.

However, I want it to be a closed bot. I'm trying to find in the documentation of telepot if there is a way to allow certain users based on there chat ID.

Does anyone know the correct syntax for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a whitelist of ID's, on a message, check if that id exists in the whitelist.